# Can't turn `&Vec<Box<str>>` into `&[&str]`

Tags: rust

I have a function in my code that takes a `&[&'a str]`:

```
fn user_quicksort<'a>(list: &[&'a str]) -> Vec<&'a str>
```

In the caller, I've got a `Box<[Box<str>]>` variable which I want to pass into it; however, Rust gives me the following error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\main.rs:36:33
   |
36 |     let sorted = user_quicksort(&input);
   |                  -------------- ^^^^^^ expected `&[&str]`, found `&Box<[Box<str>]>`
   |                  |
   |                  arguments to this function are incorrect
   |
   = note: expected reference `&[&str]`
              found reference `&Box<[Box<str>]>`
```

The reason I am using `Box<str>` instead of `String` is because `Box<str>` is immutable, faster, and smaller.

What should I do?

This is how I get `input`:

```rust
let input = fs::read_to_string("input.txt")
    .expect("Unable to read file")
    .split("\n")
    .map(|s| s.to_string().into_boxed_str())
    .collect::<Box<[Box<str>]>>();
```

Comment: Can't `user_quicksort()` be changed to expect `&mut [Box<str>]>` as parameter (in order to sort inplace)?

Comment: If you're allowed to change the signature of `user_quicksort()`, the signature `fn user_quicksort(list: &[impl AsRef<str>]) -> Vec<&str>` will allow calling it with both `&[&str]` and `&[Box<str>]` (as well as with `&[String]`). https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2a68823c548971ea2092592cab7fa03e

Comment: If you can't modify the signature of `user_quicksort()`, I don't think what you'd like to do is possible. You can't transmute `&[Box<str>]` to `&[&str]` because the `&str` is `Copy` while `Box<str>` is not, so a pathological implementation of `user_quicksort()` (that would still fulfill the signature, i.e. be safe given a `&[&str]`) could cause UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of imposing a duplication of the sequence in the sorting function, I would make it sort the sequence **inplace**.

This way, at the call-site we can choose if we want to alter the original sequence or is we want to keep it unsorted and build a shallow copy to be sorted.

It would be expensive to clone the sequence because each `Box<str>` would be cloned too.
Then our sorting function should be able to work on a sequence of `Box<str>` for the original sequence and on a sequence of `&str` for the shallow copy.
Using `impl AsRef<str>` in the parameter helps because both `Box<str>` and `&str` (obviously) can be considered as references to `str`.

```rust
fn user_quicksort(list: &mut [impl AsRef<str>]) {
    // rely on standard slice::sort_by() here
    list.sort_by(|a, b| a.as_ref().cmp(b.as_ref()));
}

fn main() {
    let mut input = std::fs::read_to_string("input.txt")
        .expect("Unable to read file")
        .split("\n")
        .map(|s| s.to_string().into_boxed_str())
        .collect::<Box<[Box<str>]>>();
    // if we want to keep the initial sequence as is,
    // then we create a shallow clone of the sequence and sort it
    let mut shallow_clone =
        input.iter().map(|s| s.as_ref()).collect::<Box<[&str]>>();
    for (s1, s2) in input.iter().zip(shallow_clone.iter()) {
        // just a check to be sure we didn't copy de str themselves
        if s1.as_ptr() != s2.as_ptr() {
            println!("!!! deep copy {:?} {:?}", s1, s2);
        }
    }
    user_quicksort(shallow_clone.as_mut());
    println!("sorted clone: {:?}", shallow_clone);
    println!("initial input: {:?}", input);
    // but if we want to sort the initial sequence,
    // no new allocation is needed
    user_quicksort(input.as_mut());
    println!("sorted input: {:?}", input);
}
/*
sorted clone: ["", "line 1", "line 2", "line 3", "line 4", "line 5"]
initial input: ["line 4", "line 1", "line 5", "line 2", "line 3", ""]
sorted input: ["", "line 1", "line 2", "line 3", "line 4", "line 5"]
*/
```

Comment: Thanks! In fact, you don't even have to rewrite `mut &[&'a str]` to `&mut [impl AsRef<str>]`. Rust figures it all out

Comment: @Antosser ah? maybe it works on your specific use-case, but in my minimal example it is rejected when I try to sort the original sequence (last line).

Comment: I didn't use your sort_by, I tweaked it a little for me